# Sentinel-2 Multiband thresholding (masking) using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, masking, multi-band

I want to extract wheat pixels from the sentinel 2 image in google earth engine. Based on field analysis pixel should satisfy 3 conditions: NDVI value between 0.6 to 0.7, NDWI value between -0.5 to -0.58 and EVI value between 0.1 to 0.18. If the pixel is true for these conditions then only its a wheat pixel of my spp. of interest. I have written a [java script link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmonish_d%2Fgee%3ABhopal_NDVI)
, but its not doing what I want. Is there any way to fulfill all the conditions? Also is it possible to apply it to image composite rather than image collection?

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");
var admin2 = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");
var Bhopal = admin2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME', 'Bhopal'))
var geometry = Bhopal.geometry()
var rgbVis = {min: 0.0, max: 3000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
var filtered = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31'))
.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
var composite = filtered.median().clip(Bhopal)
// Map.addLayer(composite, rgbVis, 'Bhopal Composite') 
// This function calculates both NDVI an d NDWI indices
// and returns an image with 2 new bands added to the original image.
function addIndices(image) {
 var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('ndwi');
return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi);
}
function addEVI(image){
var NIR = image.select('B5').divide(10000);
var RED = image.select('B4').divide(10000);
var BLUE = image.select('B2').divide(10000);
return image.addBands(image.expression(  
'2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', 
{NIR:NIR,RED:RED,BLUE:BLUE}).rename('evi'));
}
var maskedW21 = function(image) {
var NDVI = image.select(['ndvi']);
var NDWI = image.select(['ndwi']);var EVI = image.select(['evi']);
 return image.addBands(ee.Image(1).updateMask((NDVI.lte(0.6).gte(0.7)).where(NDWI,NDWI.lte(-0.5)).where(EVI,EVI.gte(0.1))).rename('W21_mask'));
// return image.addBands(ee.Image(1).updateMask((NDVI.lte(0.6).gte(0.7)).where(NDWI,NDWI.lte(-0.5).gte(-0.6))).rename('W21_mask'));};
// var maskedW21 = function(image) {
//   var NDVI = image.select(['ndvi']);//     return image.addBands(ee.Image(1).updateMask(NDVI.lte(0.5).gte(0.7)).rename('W21_mask'));};
// Map the function over the collection
var withIndices = filtered.map(addIndices).map(addEVI).map(maskedW21);
var maskBands = function(image) {return image.updateMask(image.select('W21_mask'));//.updateMask(image.select('NDVI_mask'))};
var mask_indices = withIndices.map(maskBands)  
// Composite
var composite2 = mask_indices.median().clip(Bhopal)
print(composite2)
Map.addLayer(composite2, rgbVis, 'Bhopal Composite')
var palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718','74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201','004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
var ndviVis = {min:0, max:0.5, palette: palette }
var NDVI = composite2.select('ndvi')
Map.addLayer(NDVI,ndviVis,'NDVI')
var NDWI = composite2.select('ndwi')
Map.addLayer(NDWI,ndviVis,'NDWI')
// Extract the 'ndwi' band and display a NDWI map
// use the palette ['white', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your script was the definition of the mask according to the values of interest in the NDVI, NDWI and EVI bands. In order to create a mask based on several conditions and bands you should use the function `and`. Here's a working version of your function.

```
var maskedW21 = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.select(['ndvi']);
  var NDWI = image.select(['ndwi']);
  var EVI = image.select(['evi']);
  
  // Define masks according to the desired thresholds
  var maskNDVI = NDVI.lte(0.7).and(NDVI.gte(0.6));
  var maskNDWI = NDWI.lte(-0.5).and(NDWI.gte(-0.58));
  var maskEVI = EVI.lte(0.18).and(EVI.gte(0.1));
  
  // Make a mask that fulfills the three masks and rename the band
  var mask = maskNDVI.and(maskNDWI)
  .and(maskEVI)
  .rename('W21_mask');

  // Add the mask as a band to the image and update the mask for the image
  return image.addBands(mask)
  .updateMask(mask);
};

var withIndices = filtered.map(addIndices).map(addEVI);

var mask_indices = withIndices.map(maskedW21);
```

Finally, if you wish to apply the function to an image composite rather than an ImageCollection, you can do that by calling directly the function over the image. For example.

```
maskedW21(Image);
```